# Google drive display imag urls in web app

Tags: python, google-drive-api, streamlit

I have stored a bunch of images on google drive via the Desktop app under G:\google_drive\sdr\pos.

The images names are stored in a database (image1.png, image2.png, image3.png).

How can I use an url and display the images in my streamlit app? The google drive url does not contain the image file name:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AWhXeAGB8qBWe9kItc5zW9eLytIguOQF/view

How to link the url automatically to the image files?

Comment: Drive isn't a file hosting site even if you set the files public you are going to get usage errors very fast

Comment: Ok, then I have to switch to an alternative

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to format the URL using a different structure, I found some examples,

1. Identify the ID of the file, in this case `1AWhXeAGB8qBWe9kItc5zW9eLytIguOQF`.
2. Use this template `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=YOUR_ID`
3. Result: `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1AWhXeAGB8qBWe9kItc5zW9eLytIguOQF`

Sample:

[image]

Code:

`<img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1AWhXeAGB8qBWe9kItc5zW9eLytIguOQF">`

---

I found this solution [here](https://gist.github.com/evansims/f23e2f49e3d4be793038).

Comment: Thanks but this is not an option for many images.

Comment: How will the images be available to the internet if not through Google Drive? How are the other "many images" different from the example? Examples for different scenarios could be helpful.

Comment: They are directly stored on my local machine via the Desktop app (windows path)